# Ads customisation for Google AdSense

Tags: ads, adsense, mobile-website

On my website, 90% of traffic coming from mobile devices. I want to show ads related to the app install ads something like this

[image]

but I don't know how to achieve that. Is there any customization needed in adsense account? I visit on my website multiple times from my mobile but not able to see these type of ads shown in the above image instead of that ads are simple(infeed for service, online shopping etc.). But when I visit another website(from which I took the image) It shows always these kinds of app installation ads. Please let me know if there is any kind of customisation option in the Adsense account to prefer these kind of ads for mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

According to [google's own documentation](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722028?hl=en), you can "you can set your ads to target specific devices and ad space by clicking Devices in the page menu."

Also, refer to [this](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7101715?hl=en&ref_topic=3121772) to target mobile devices only.

Answer (score 0):

AdSense does not let you choose to exclusively show App Install Display ads on your mobile site.

The AdSense system will automatically 'learn' what type of ad formats your site visitors interact the most with. Over time AdSense will show ad formats that generate highest RPMs more often.

I would recommend to not worry too much about the ad format AdSense is showing on your site and focus on user growth and content creation. If AdSense 'learns' that the install ads perform best for overall revenue, then those will be the ad type shown most often.